# Click HTML img tag and update MySQL with jQuery/AJAX using PDO

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I have this HTML:

```
<a href="#"  ><div class="menu"><img src="<?php echo $value->capa; ?>" class="img-rounded" id="item" alt="Cinque Terre" alt="Lights"></a></div>
```

I have that part to have the ID from img hidden:

```
<input type="hidden" id="idLivro" name="idLivro" value="<?=$value->id?>">
```

And this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu").click(function(){
        var idLivro = document.getElementById("idLivro");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'updateBadge.php?id='+idLivro,
            method: 'GET'
        })
    });
});
```

updateBadge.php:

```
require_once 'classes/Crud.php';

$banco = new Usuarios();

$idLivro = $_GET['idLivro'];

$banco->updateBadge($idLivro);
```

What I want to do, is when someone click that link(img) where have a badge next to it, it increment by 1 the respective column in DB.

But, the part where I have the update method is inside a class:

```
public function updateBadge($id){
        $sql  = "UPDATE $this->table SET badge = (badge+1) WHERE id = :id";
        $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
        return $stmt->execute();
    }
```

How can I use AJAX to call this function to update the badge counter?

**EDITED: I've change the code using the comments below. Still not working**

Comment: First fix the PHP. 2 placeholders and only one bindParam will cause you probelms

Comment: Second fix the method to recieve 2 parameters

Comment: Third check that the method is called with 2 parameters

Comment: Fourth, work out where you are going to store the `id` and `badge` data in the HTML so that the javascript can see it and pass it to the PHP when you run the AJAX call

Comment: Fifth, change the javascript to get the `id` and `badge` data from whereever you decided to store it in the HTML

Comment: Or maybe consider changing the query to `$sql  = "UPDATE $this->table SET badge = badge+1 WHERE id = :id";` then you can forget comments 1+2+3 and half of 4+5

Comment: sixth where do you actually increment  the db value here?

Comment: Thanks for this help. I'll edit my question with the changes.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You need a script (e.g. `Users.php` as you call it in the AJAX request. In this `Users.php` you have to instantiate your class and call the `updateBadge`-method with the repective parameters, that have also to be sent in your AJAX request.

And if you just like to increment the badge column write following query (then only one bind param is fine):

```
$sql = "UPDATE $this->table SET badge = (badge+1) WHERE id = :id";
```

To get the ID to the AJAX request you need the ID somewhere in the HTML, get it via jQuery and pass it to your URL like

```
$.ajax({ 
     url: 'classes/Users.php?id='+theJsVariableYouStoredTheIdIn,
     method: 'GET'
 })
```

Then you can access it in you `Users.php` via `$_GET['id']`

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll update my question with edited code.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Is the value in the database not updated after the AJAX request or simply the frontend? If the value in DB is updated and the frontend isn't, you have to add the `.done` function like in nimour pristou's answer.

Comment: I saw that moment, that nimour pristou is updating the user ID on a successful response and not the badge-image. So in `.done` you have to replace/update your badge-image, with the inremented version (get `src` attribute of the image, increment by 1 and set as that value as the `src` attribute if the src is only a number)

Answer (score 0):

page updateBadge.php

```
 <?php
    require_once 'classes/Crud.php';
    //function isAjax()  To test whether the query is in Ajax
    public function isAjax()
    {
        return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']== 'XMLHttpRequest';
    }
    if(isAjax()){
        $banco = new Usuarios();
        $idLivro = $_GET['idLivro'];
        if($banco->updateBadge($idLivro)){
            echo "updated";
        }
    }
```

And your script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu").click(function(){
        var idLivro = document.getElementById("idLivro");
        var badge=  $('#vidLivro').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'updateBadge.php?id='+idLivro,
            method: 'GET'
        })
        .done(function(data,text,jqxhr){
            if(jqxhr.responssetext=='updated'){
               $('#vidLivro').val(badge+1);  

            }
        })
    });
});
```